# C++: basic_string::_M_construct null not valid error for Graph BFS algorithm

Tags: c++, string

This is a standard BFS algorithm for graphs using templates. The algorithm works well for all basic data types except for string. I know it is caused when a null value is passed to std::string(), but I can't figure out exactly why there should be a null string in the first place in the code.

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>

    using namespace std;

    template < typename T >
    class Graph {
unordered_map < T, list < T >> adjList;

public:

  void addEdge(T u, T v, bool birdir = true) {
    adjList[u].push_back(v);
    if (birdir)
      adjList[v].push_back(u);
  }

void printG() {
  for (auto i: adjList) {
    cout << i.first << "->";
    for (auto nodes: i.second) {
      cout << nodes << ",";

    }

    cout << endl;
  }
}
void BFS(T src) {
  queue < T > Q;
  unordered_map < T, bool > visited;
  Q.push(src);
  //Q.push(nullptr);
  visited[src] = true;

  while (!Q.empty()) {
            T f = Q.front();
            Q.pop();

            cout << f << " -- ";

            for (auto neighbor: adjList[f]) {
              if (!visited[neighbor]) {
              visited[neighbor] = true;
              Q.push(neighbor);
            }
         }

  }
}
    };

 int main() {
  Graph < string > * g = new Graph < string > ();
  g - > addEdge("0", "1", false);
  g - > addEdge("1", "3");
  //g->printG();
  cout << endl;
  g - > BFS(0);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is how you call `BFS`.  You use

```
g - > BFS(0);
```

which tries to construct a `std::string` from `0`.  `0` is the null pointer constant and since `std::string` has an overload that takes a `const char*`, the compiler calls that constructor.  That is not valid to do though since the pointer cannot be a null pointer.  This causes the exception to you encounter.  You'll need to change code to

```
g - > BFS("");
```

or even simpler

```
g - > BFS();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Graph<std::string>::BFS` is a member function that takes a `std::string`. When you call `g->BFS(0);`, the `0` is used to construct the `std::string` argument, and calls the constructor that takes a `const char*`. This calls `std::string::string(nullptr)`.

To avoid `0` being interpreted as a null pointer in your code in gcc, use `-Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant`. You probably meant `g->BFS("0")` (The string `"0"`)